# Meaning of "time situation"

Tags: meaning

I have heard the sentence "*we have a time situation here*" in many places. Although one could easily decipher it means we are short of time when asking someone to do something... But I couldn't find the term "*time situation*" in a dictionary or some usage of the word "*time*" as a verb or noun which could be used in this way. I am probably not looking correctly.

Comment: It sounds "uneducated" to me, but even without a specific context, I'm sure it will always mean that the current situation is [***time-critical***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/time-critical.html) in some way. Most likely, there's a ***deadline*** date/time for something to happen, in a context where there's some degree of risk that the deadline might not be met. OR that whatever needs to be done must be done ***immediately / as soon as possible***.

Comment: I heard that recently in a 2000 hollywood movie

Answer (score 2):

In general, "an X situation," where X is some noun, means "a situation, insofar as X is concerned." [An example usage:](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/07/opinion/new-york-city-budget.html)

> We’re going to be in **a horrible budget situation** for years.

This means: "we're going to be in a horrible situation, insofar as our budget is concerned, for years." Alternatively: "regarding our budget, we're going to be in a horrible situation for years."

So: "we have a time situation" means "we have a situation, insofar as time is concerned." [In this case, "situation" means:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/situation) "a critical, problematic, or striking set of circumstances."

So your sentence means:

> We have a problematic set of circumstances here, insofar as time is concerned.

This essentially means:

> The amount of time that we have is a problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

The term "time situation" wouldn't normally exist outside of a sentence such as this.

The sentence comes from the more general use of the term "situation" in phrases like "we have a situation here", and people have taken that sentence construction and applied it more specifically to time.

Even the sentence "we have a situation" isn't exactly "grammatically correct", it would probably be more correct to say something like "we have a difficult situation" or "a tricky situation" but as with many things in English people take shortcuts with language for humour, dramatic effect, or brevity.